# Strange Windows 8 and 10 issue

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-10, audio, services

I'm having a strange issue on both Windows 8 and Windows 10. I think it might be to do with services not responding properly. Here are my symptoms:

1. Sound delay/lag. Every sound plays with a slight delay of about 2-3 seconds, unless there is continuous sound output like in a game. When I am playing a game, there isn't a delay in things like menu sounds or whatnot, but when I'm on the desktop and play an audio file the player hangs for 2-3 seconds before playing the output. Tested with multiple audio players and multiple headphones. I found that when forcing a particular service (the name escapes me, I currently don't have access to this PC) to run the sound played just fine again.
2. Chrome failing to start and uninstall. Chrome just doesn't start, or takes upwards of 5 minutes to open (without any tabs open) and after all that, the tabs hang and won't load. Firefox works fine. Also, the uninstaller doesn't run at all. I've also tried clearing my profiles twice and that doesn't have any difference. Chrome has a service, `gupdate`, that is stopped and when I start it in task manager it stops immediately after. Since `gupdate` is the updating service I'm not sure - it might be meant to stay stopped.
3. Group policy service not starting. When I log on I get a balloon notification notifying me that the group policy service hasn't started and non-administrators can't log in. Sure enough, task manager reveals `gpsvc` is stopped and trying to start it yields an "Access denied" error.

So this weekend I upgraded to Windows 10 in a bid to fix these issues, but the problem persists. Since Windows 10 keeps your files, it might be something in the user profile or the like that persisted during upgrade.

#### Additional information:

- Reboots help a bit, but not always
- For the sound issue, there was a fix involving the registry editor but that only fixed it for ~5 restarts.
- I use Norton 360 as my AV
- I have an AMD CPU and GPU
- `sfc /scannow` finds no issues